# Google DataFlow Batch type job stuck at BigQueryIO.Write/StreamingInserts step

Tags: apache-beam, dataflow

I have a Batch type dataflow job. I'm reading ids from GCS file, calling some API for each id, API returns N items per each id. Then I try to write all those items into BigQuery table.

The process gets stuck with the message:

```
Processing stuck in step BigQueryIO.Write/StreamingInserts/StreamingWriteTables/Reshuffle/GroupByKey/Read for at least 05m00s without outputting or completing in state read-shuffle
```

Note: it only happens when I use more than 1 worker. With 1 worker all works fine.

UPDATE:
Parameters for dataflow:

```
    DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
    options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);
    options.setProject("my-project");
    options.setJobName("my-job");
    options.setRegion("us-east1");
    options.setWorkerMachineType("n1-standard-1");
    options.setNumWorkers(2);
    options.setMaxNumWorkers(2);
    options.setSubnetwork("some_subnetwork");
    options.setStagingLocation("gs://bla/staging");
    options.setGcpTempLocation("gs://bla/temp");
```

UPDATE 2:
With 1 worker all works fine for small amount of input ids, because Reshuffle finishes successfully only after all entities are retrieved. If I have a lot of input ids Reshuffle stucks waiting for all previous steps to finish.

Comment: Do you specify additional parameters when running more workers? Additionally, please check [limatations doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/quotas), do you 
exceeds any? Which SDK version do you use?

Comment: I'm testing on a very small amount of data (several ids, N = few dozens), so no limitations are exceeded. I'm using SDK 2.17.0.

Comment: I've updated question with dataflow parameters

Comment: It can be connected to your SDK version, which has known JVM bug and Beam introduced a workaround for versions 2.19.0 and later. Please upgrade your Apache Beam SDK, and run your job again. If it wouldn't help: Is your job failed or just stack (not finished at all)? Could you please provide more stack trace output? What kind of API are you calling for?